# Cucumber specify examples for different sites

Tags: java, spring, cucumber

I'm writing test automation for 2 web sites and i want to use same scenarious but with different data, what is the way of doing that?

```
   Feature: Search

  @smoke @search
  Scenario Outline: I want to search for products
     Given I enter "<keyword>" as a keyword to a search field
     Then I should see search results page
     Then I should see at least <count> results containing "<keyword>"
```

for hotels.com

```
Examples:
| keyword     | count       |
| hotel       | 3           |
```

for cars.com

```
Examples:
| keyword     | count       |
| cars        | 3           |
```

i'm using spring boot with java

Comment: Use (hotel or car) tag on top of the examples keyword. hotel tag for hotels data etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use (hotel or car) tag on top of the examples keyword. hotel tag for hotels data etc etc – Grasshopper